# No exact match was found when add user to SP2013 site

Tags: user-profile-service, people-picker

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm. We need to add a user "Subdomain\peterpan" to site collection A's permission group. But it returns "No exact match was found" error.

We checked in Central Admin -> Manage Profile Service: User Profile Service Application -> Manage User Profiles. The userID is found. Also we can add another user "Subdomain\alice" to that site collection A. In addition, we can add "Subdomain\peterpan" to another site collection B.

In the form assigning user permission, when I type in "Subdomain\" the dropdown list will show me "Subdomain\peterpan" (nothing else, only peterpan). When select it and click "Share" button, system return "user does not exist or is not unique" error.

In the user profile sync, we have setup to sync the DOMAIN.com. "Subdomain" is a child domain of DOMAIN.com.

What could cause the No exact match was found error?

Comment: Is this for 2013? Try to just go for the username. Is the user a new employee? Are you using ADFS?

Comment: It is SP2013. Tried username, subdomain.com\xxx, all fail. Peterpan is old employee so his account exist long ago. ADFS is using. Our farm is on Sharepoint.com domain. domain.com is a separated domain we added to UPS

Answer (score 0):

The issue and solution is described here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2874332

Good luck!

Comment: Please post the important parts of the article in your answer, link only answers become useless if the link is broken.

Comment: Checked according to provided method and seems not my case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried verifying if the accountname is known twice in that site collection? I suggest using the people picker again to see if there's 2 suggestions underneath that "No exact match was found" warning.

The more thorough way is to check the UserHiddenInfo list in the site collection root:

```
/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx
```

source: https://zimmergren.net/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list/

I've had it occur to me a few times that somehow, there was an AD issue with alias's or duplicate emails in the AD domain and after fixing AD we had to clear that user from this list before SP would act normal again.